# How to use a different fontfamily for italic text

Tags: fonts, macros, patching, typefaces

I want my document to change from CMR to Garamond when using italic typeface, and automatically go back when not using italic. Preferably would this happen when I just issue the `\textit{}` command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining old-style and modern typefaces is rarely advisable, but if you’re compiling with `luatex` or `xetex` and using `fontspec`, it’s easy to choose an italic with an entirely different name from the roman. Here’s an example, with two typefaces that do go together:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}
\setmainfont{Poliphilus MT Pro}[
  ItalicFont={Blado MT Pro Italic}]
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
\begin{document}
Ayer your seuerall roomes with Charcole fiers, made in stone pans or
Chafingdishes, and not in Chimneys: set your pans in the middle of the
roomes: ayer euery roome once a weeke (at the least) and put into your
fyre a little quantitie of \textit{Francomsence, Iuniper,} dryed
\textit{Rosemary,} or of \textit{Bay-leaues.}
% from ‘Good Councell against the plague’ by ‘a learned Phisition,’ 1592
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

These typefaces have no bold, but if they did, a line such as `BoldItalicFont={Blado MT Pro Bold Italic}` would be necessary.

Comment: To be fully old style, shouldn't all nouns have an initial capital letter? And  italic font also use a long s:-)

Comment: @Bernard This book is more fun than anyone should have during a pandemic. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/62182/62182-h/62182-h.htm  I like its use of ‘VVorme-wood,’ capitalized.

Comment: Beautiful dropped capital! Why didn't you use one? There's a package by Clea F. Rees making some available in LaTeX…

Comment: @Bernard The original is at https://archive.org/details/2247046R.nlm.nih.gov/page/n9/mode/2up  I should have set this in blackletter, with roman where I now have italic.  Someday when there’s nothing else to do…

Comment: I already had some fun during my spare time with some of Edward Lear's nonsense stories.